# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JavaScript, I want to convert html table to pdf, below is the error that I get when clicking a button "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document". the error is shown on this line " return html2canvas(form,"

This is what I tried, When I click the generate report button I expecting the table to be converted to pdf. The pdf must be converted from html2canvas

```
 <button type="submit" id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-primary" >
                                    Generate Report </button>


 <div class="container-fluid px-4" id="transactions">

                        <img src="pl-removebg-preview.png" class="img-fluid logo" style="margin-top:5%; margin-left:35%;">
                        <h4 style="justify-content:center; text-align: center; margin-top:5%;">Transactions report from <b id="from"> </b> to <b id="to"> </b></h4>
                        <div class="row my-5">
                            <div class="col table-responsive">
                                <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Merchant Name</th>
                                            <th>Distributor Number</th>
                                            <th>Provider</th>
                                            <th>Customer Merchant</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                        
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="client_data">

                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>Total</th>
                                            <th id="total"></th>
                                            
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                                <nav class="pagination-container">

                                    <div id="pagination-numbers">

                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

above is the html part of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var form = $('#transactions'),
    cache_width = form.width(),
    a4 = [610.28, 841.89]; // for a4 size paper width and height  

  $('#create_pdf').on('click', function () {
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    createPDF();
  });

  function createPDF() {
    event.preventDefault();
    getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {
      var
        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
        doc = new jsPDF({
          unit: 'px',
          format: 'a4'
        });
      doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 20, 20);
      doc.save('Pay_Lesotho_Report.pdf');
      form.width(cache_width);
    });
  }

  function getCanvas() {
    form.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');
    return html2canvas(form, {
      imageTimeout: 2000,
      removeContainer: true
    });
  }
});
```

above is the javascript code that handles the converting of html to pdf

Comment: You did not provide the details about the error (e.g. which line the error is thrown or stack trace) but try `html2canvas(form.get(0),` instead of `html2canvas(form,`.

Comment: the error is shown on this line "  return html2canvas(form,"

Comment: The htmltocanvas function seems to expect an html element, you're passing a jQuery object. Use `.get(0)` to the the html element inside the jquery object.